# Feminist linguistics?

Tags: linguistics, feminism

So I've noticed commonly in young girls, they express themselves with words like: "I do not feel pretty." Upon noticing this, I find it tragic that the very framing of a problem to revolve around an idea of worth tied to one's physical appearance. Is there a strain of the feminist movement that seeks to provide a linguistic framework for an autonomous vocabulary? How does this tie into the transgender movement's linguistic battle?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148163/discussion-on-question-by-more-anonymous-feminist-linguistics); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Could you re-phrase that, please?

When young girls say 'I do not feel pretty' what makes that about feminist linguistics, let alone philosophy, as opposed to the girls' personal feelings?

it is tragic that the very framing of a problem might revolve around an idea of worth tied to physical appearance; even more than that your framing of the problem might stem from an unstated agenda.

What could whether a strain of the feminist movement seeking to provide a linguistic framework for autonomous vocabulary change? 

How does this tie into the transgender movement's linguistic battle?

Comment: "even more than that your framing of the problem might stem from an unstated agenda" --- what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will find that a Google search for "feminist linguistics" returns a plethora of results. You may care to browse through those.

It might be an idea to start with [SEP - Feminist philosophy of language](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/feminism-language/) and/or [Wikipedia - Feminist Language Reform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feminist_language_reform)

Your supplementary question about the transgender issue suggests that you already know something about that, so I assume you don't need references for it. I don't know how far anyone has considered them in relation to each other.

Transgender linguistics seems to be a rather specialized area. [Wikipedia - LGBT linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBT_linguistics) may help. I found [Judith Butler - Gender and the Trans Experience](https://news/2009-judith-butler-on-gender-and-the-trans-experience-one-should-be-free-to-determine-the-course-of-one-s-gendered-life) which may help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Umm about: "so I assume you don't need references for it" I have just spoken to members of that community that have given me that impression (of linguistic awareness). So actually references would be nice?

Comment: I'll see what I can find.

Comment: You could start by watching the 'Barbie' movie. It's awesome.

Comment: I do wanna watch it. Didn't do well in India though. I suspect it didn't vibe with the Indian feminist.